# openstreet map using node-geocoder sending garbage value

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, geocoding, openstreetmap

geocoder module to hit open street map
but it seems to be returning a garbage value

below is the url and its request and response headers

> url parameters

```
{"host":"nominatim.openstreetmap.org","path":"/search?format=json&addressdetails=1&q=adyar"}
```

> response headers

```
{"date":"Fri, 20 Jun 2014 06:48:57 GMT","server":"Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)","content-location":"reverse.php","vary":"negotiate,accept","tcn":"choice","x-powered-by":"PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11","access-control-allow-methods":"OPTIONS,GET","access-control-max-age":"8640000","access-control-allow-origin":"*","connection":"close","transfer-encoding":"chunked","content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
```

Below is the response i'm receiving

```
[ { latitude: '25.0706658',
longitude: '34.2062962',
country: 'Ù
ØµØ± (Egypt)',
city: undefined,
zipcode: undefined,
streetName: '212',
streetNumber: undefined,
countryCode: 'eg',
state: 'Ø§Ù
           Ø¨Ø­Ø± Ø§Ù
                     Ø£Ø­Ù
 Ù
Ø±',
stateCode: undefined } ]
```

I'm receiving garbage values as above dont know where i'm going wrong.Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That's not garbage, you just need to decode it correctly.

Comment: No idea, sorry. I'm not familiar with node.js.